# use OpenMP and mpz_t malloc causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, openmp, gmp

I need to use OpenMP programming with mpz_t array of 2^15 size to parallel the following code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(j,temp3)
for(j=Real;j<LL;j++)//l
    {
        for(__int64_t k=0;k<=((j/(Real*1.0))/(log(sieve[i])/log(2.0)));k++)//l5
        {
            if((((j/(Real*1.0)-k*(log(sieve[i])/log(2.0)))<LL))&&(((j/(Real*1.0)-k*(log(sieve[i])/log(2.0)))>0)))// can log() use __int64_t?
                mpz_add(temp3[j],temp3[j],temp2[(int)floor((j-k*Real*(log(sieve[i])/log(2.0))))]);
        }
        mpz_add_ui(temp3[j],temp3[j],(int)floor(((j/(Real*1.0))/(log(sieve[i])/log(2.0)))));
    }
```

I initial the array temp3 like this:

```
mpz_t temp3[LL];
```

and it causes Segmentation fault.So I tried to write like this:

```
mpz_t *temp3=(mpz_t *)malloc(sizeof(mpz_t)*LL);
```

it also causes Segmentation fault, and the malloc operation isn't successful.
How to solve?  Thanks!

Comment: You never call `mpz_init`? Why are you making temp3 private?

Comment: I called mpz_init. temp3[] can get right value in parallel without set private?

Comment: `private` means: "make a copy of it for each thread". What does making a copy mean in this case?

Comment: Got it. The program works well. THX

Answer (score 0):

When temp3 is an array (`mpz_t temp3[ll]`) and you declare it private then OpenMP makes private versions of the the array for each thread (i.e. it allocates separate private memory from the stack of each thread).  However, in the second case using malloc `temp3` is only a pointer (arrays and pointers are not the same thing) and when you pass a private pointer then OpenMP only makes private versions of the pointer for each thread (it allocates no memory).

In the first case the crash could be due to the array being larger than the stack size.  In the second case the private versions of the pointers are never initialized (as they would be with firstprivate) so they point to unknown memory addresses which likely causes the crash.

The solution is simple.  **Don't declare `temp3` private.  It should be shared.**

You could try leaving `temp3` as private when it's a pointer if you use firstprivate but I don't think that's a good idea.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int x[10];
    printf("%p\n", x);
    #pragma omp parallel private(x) 
    {
        printf("%p\n", x);
    }

    int* y = (int*)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
    #pragma omp parallel firstprivate(y)
    {
        printf("%p\n", y);
    }
}
```